# NDB using too many memory for a simple .put()?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have an Appengine app in Python (Flask) and I've started tracing the memory consumption following errors on the console.

I've narrowed down the culprit to a simple `.put()` from an NDB entry and I don't know what to do to fix that issue.

Here's the model I use from NDB :

```
class MassiveEntry(ndb.Model):
    massive_id = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=True)
    row     = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=True)

    name    = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    address = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    email   = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False, default=None)
    reason  = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False, default=None)

    # Used for Tasks processing :
    contact_id = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False, default=None)

    processing = ndb.BooleanProperty(name="is_processing", default=True, indexed=True)  # Only when searching contact processing is set to True
    treated = ndb.BooleanProperty(name="is_treated", default=False, indexed=True)
```

When a customer upload a CSV file on my app, I read it and add as many MassiveEntry entries has lines. After that, I have a asynchronous task that read the next available (`processing` = False, `treated` = False) entry, set the `entry.processing` to True and treat the data. Once it's done, it updates the `entry.treated` to True, and check the next available entry.

I get a list of next available entries by using this request :

```
entries = MassiveEntry.query().filter(cls.massive_id == massive).filter(cls.processing == False).filter(cls.treated == False).iter()
```

(massive is an id from the database).

Then, I loop over the results to load a few next available items.

I checked the memory stats when loading the entries, nothing changes. but when I do

```
entry.processing = True
entry.put()
```

The memory takes 10Mb! This happens when the related `MassiveEntry.massive_id` value contains more than 50k entries.

To sum up :

```
# Memory stat : no changes
entries = MassiveEntry.query().filter(cls.massive_id == massive).filter(cls.processing == False).filter(cls.treated == False).iter()
# Memory stat : no changes
for entry in entries:
     # Memory stat : no changes
     # Do some stuff
     # Memory stat : no changes
     entry.treated = True
     entry.put() # HERE! The memory goes up to 10Mb ONLY WHEN the massive_id is related to around 50k rows in the datastore.
     # Memory stat : +10Mb !
```

Do you have any idea why? And how can I prevent that? If needed, I can provide more code but I think this is enough.

Comment: seeing this on dev_appserver or out on App Engine?  Are there indexes on MassiveEntry?

Comment: Yes, as you can see, massive_id and row have an index. And it's on App Engine :)

Comment: In your model `massive_id` is just an integer, what do you mean by `contains more than 50k entries`?

Comment: The `massive_id` comes from the id in the database. But for each lines, I've stored them in NDB and that's where the `massive_id` come from. And that's also why I can have 50k entries for the same `massive_id` value.

Comment: I was actually asking about composite indexes.  Anyway you could experiment with `batch_size` in the [query options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queryclass#kwdargs_options).  I would also try a composite index on the three fields you are querying on.  I wonder if some in-memory filtering is going on.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. While trying to find the memory leak, I discovered that NDB goes in a loop when calling `.next()` on the result set many times. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Do you see the long `put()` (and/or the memory spikes) in the development environment or on GAE/in production?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Can you point me in the direction of where I can see this? I'm not sure I'm using the right tool on Appengine.

Comment: @CyrilN. You're stating in the question the memory goes up :) that's what I'm asking about. It *might* help describe how you reached that conclusion as well (but I'm not sure).

Comment: Remember when you call put() the object will be encoded as a Protobuf, Does the memory use go up at the point of the first put() or after some puts().  You probably find the batching/prefetch kicks in at some point. Does it really matter ?  Once you have completed processing and return does the memory consumption for the instance drop back down ?

Comment: Turns out the memory spike is really odd, some times it's at some place, sometimes it's completely elsewhere ... (I've added logs about memory usage all along the code).
But since then I've updated my servers to one with double memory (from 128Mb to 256) and since then, I didn't not had any memory error. So maybe it was just my work that was too heavy for a 128Mb instance... I'm not more advanced about it though ;)

Comment: So thank you very much DanCornilescu and tim-hoffman for your help,  I appreciate!